# Display Multiple results with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Google maps and returning all the long/Lat and Info boxes, which is working. I want to populate some info about the results I am getting back as well. I though I could use `jquery.html()` and it all works good but only brings back the last one. It is in my `$.each()`, I moved it to different places in the `.each` call and can't seem to suss it out.

```
 console.log(data.d);
                var response = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $.each(response, function (index, po) {
                    // map
                    var marker = map.addMarker(
                        {
                            lat: (parseFloat(po.Outward)),
                            lng: (parseFloat(po.Inward)),
                            content: '<span style="color:#00539f;">' + po.CompanyName + '</span>',
                            id: 1// adding custom properties to the object

                        },$('.address-results').html("<div class='address-result'><h5 class='bold-blue'>" + po.CompanyName + "</h5><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign address-icon'></span><br/><span>" + po.Street + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Town + "</span><br/><span>" + po.County + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Postcode + "</span></div>")
                        );
                     // I have tried here as well    
                });
```

What should I be doing to populate all the boxes of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can empty result first and then use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. This will will append the result instead of replacing it.

```
console.log(data.d);
//empty result
$('.address-results').empty();
var response = JSON.parse(data.d);
$.each(response, function (index, po) {
    // map
    var marker = map.addMarker(
        {
            lat: (parseFloat(po.Outward)),
            lng: (parseFloat(po.Inward)),
            content: '<span style="color:#00539f;">' + po.CompanyName + '</span>',
            id: 1// adding custom properties to the object

        },$('.address-results').append("<div class='address-result'><h5 class='bold-blue'>" + po.CompanyName + "</h5><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign address-icon'></span><br/><span>" + po.Street + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Town + "</span><br/><span>" + po.County + "</span><br/><span>" + po.Postcode + "</span></div>")
        );
     // I have tried here as well    
});
```